# Resend Code stop when the application is closed or move to other application

Tags: java, android, firebase, user-interface, authentication

I create the authenticate with a firebase library, auth UI. the authenticate is running well, but the resend code to stop and not working when moving to other applications or application is closing.

I don't understand it.

```
private void login() {

    //library authenticate
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                          .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build())).build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN); //nama request kode


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // RC_SIGN_IN is the request code you passed into startActivityForResult(...) when starting the sign in flow.
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

            // Successfully signed in
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                startTheActivity();
                return;
            } else {
                // Sign in failed
                if (response == null) {

                    // User pressed back button
                    Util.showSnackbar(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.sign_in_cancelled));

                    return;
                }

                if (response.getError().getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {

                    Util.showSnackbar(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.no_internet_connection));

                    return;
                }

                if (response.getError().getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR) {
                    Util.showSnackbar(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.unknown_error));
                    return;
                }
            }

            Util.showSnackbar(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.unknown_sign_in_response));
        }
    }
```

I expect when the resend code running and I move to another application. the resend code should be running to. but, that happened the resend code stops and must be back to login activity for a repeat.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: app not crashes. resend code just stop and the timer not running